# Emacs 23.2.1 .emacs file permission

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I am having trouble with setting up the .emacs file so that I, group and others can all read my files. 
I played around with C-x C-q but after I open the file and save it again only I can read/write the file. I have also used chmod +r (filename), but the problem happens again when I reload emacs. I don't want to use chmod +r everytime I edit my files.
I am using Ubuntu 11.04 Codename: natty and connecting to a server that uses Mac OSX 10.5.8. I use sftp to connect to the server.

I have checked the umask on both machines and they are both 22 or 0022. I don't know if the sftp or .emacs file is causing this error. I just want to know if I am doing the whole thing wrong or something in emacs isn't setup up right.

Comment: did you check with starting with `emacs -Q`. bit unclear to me about what is happening. could you show minimal example like, `ls -l myfile` before and after editing.

Comment: @kindahero I just tried using emacs -Q but I think it is still causing the problem.
Before edit: 
[server:~] myusername% ls -l test23
-rw-r--r--  1 myusername  staff  15 Jun 23 11:03 test23            Then I open the file using emacs installed on my computer, edited the file and saved it: 
[server:~] myusername% ls -l test23
-rw-------  1 myusername  staff  14 Jun 23 11:07 test23

If I use chmod +r while emacs is running, nothing happens to file permissions. As soon as I exit emacs and reload it, the problem starts again.

Comment: Before edit: [server:~] myusername% ls -l test23 -rw-r--r-- 1 myusername staff 15 Jun 23 11:03 test23 
After edit:
[server:~] myusername% ls -l test23 -rw------- 1 myusername staff 14 Jun 23 11:07 test23

Comment: These should be `ls -al` since `.emacs` is a hidden file (name starts with a dot).

Answer (score -1):

If you want *all files* in your `$HOME` directory to be *readable by all*, run :

```
find ~/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

to set their permissions (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1163294/1449460)). This is unrelated with emacs opening them : emacs will just follow the rights the filesystem constrains it to.

If the files permissions happen to change while you're away, something must be changing them, and you should look for that.

---

It also unrelated to with emacs being able to write in **buffers** that happen to visit these files. You should always be able to edit buffers, you can allow/prevent this with <kbd>C-x C-q</kbd>. The thing is if you make a non-writtable file's buffer writtable, you won't be able to save the changes to disk, and on the contrary, if you make a writtable file's buffer read-only, you could save any change to disk, but you prevent yourself from making such changes inside the emacs buffer. I don't see why you'd want to use that, from what you describe.

> C-x C-q runs the command toggle-read-only
>   Change whether this *buffer* is read-only.